# java jackson: get from url rest web service call pojo's (with inner pojo's) as json and map them back to pojo

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I'm using jackson, the scenario is:

1. In client (Android) generate url call to web service
2. The web service return "complex pojo" (has class members as other pojo) as json
3. Back in client map the json to pojo

I don't know how to complete this code to get things work although I searched all over and figured out the following start point, but then I completely stacked and I need help...

1. The "complex pojo":

   ```
   public class MyPojo {
       private List<MyOtherPojo> myOtherPojo;
       private List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMaps;
       private Map<String, String> map;
       //Constructors, getters & setters
   }
   ```
2. The code at client:

   ```
   String wsURI = "server.com/myservice?param1=a&param2=b";
   try {
       URL url = new URL(wsURI);
       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
       StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
       String aux = "";
       while ( (aux = in.readLine()) != null) {
           sbuilder.append(aux);
       }
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       //TODO get myPojo object from his representation as string at sbuilder.toString(); 
       myPojo = ???;
   } catch (Exception e) {}
   ```

Comment: You know ObjectMapper accepts an InputStream in it's readXxx methods. You don't need to get it in a String first. Also if the JSON is mapped correctly to the Java class it _should_ just work, using the most simple `mapper.readValue(inputStream, MyPojo.class)`. If it doesn't work, you might need to post a snippet of the JSON (at least enough for us to test, with the Java class you provided)

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks, you mean just do this: `MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), MyPojo.class);` And how it will handle the inner pojo (`MyOtherPojo` class)?

Comment: InputStreamReader is not an InputStream. connection.getInputStream returns an InputStream. But I think the method also accepts a Reader (which InputStreamReader is). Not 100% sure. _"How will it handle the inner pojo?"_ Like I said if the JSON maps properly to the complete structure of the POJO (recursively also), it should just _work_. If it it doesn't work, then we would need the see the exception, the structure of the Java classes, and the JSON

Comment: @peeskillet you mean this: `MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), MyPojo.class);`?

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks! It`s working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION thanks to @peeskillet:

`MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), MyPojo.class);`